# Alien race cat type people bounty hunters

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Heard about this from a friend.  Story about race of alien cat type people who capture other aliens and turn them over to be hunted by a race of shape shifting aliens. Human in the story is caught while sailing solo across the ocean. Human is then placed in confinement with a 7 foot t-Rex alien? Looking for a title on this one.

Comment: Book, TV, movie?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153819/hunger-games-style-alien-book (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Marion Zimmer Bradley's *Hunters of the Red Moon*.  There was also a sequel, *The Survivors*, that she co-wrote with her brother, Paul Zimmer.

Answer (score 3):

Larry Niven had a bunch of short stories and a few novels about the Kzinti who were warrior type race of bipedal cat-aliens with a variety of themes, including some bounty hunter stories, I believe.  It's been so long since I've read any of them and I only read two or three, so this is just a suggestion.

Comment: I will check into it, looking forward to it!