# Hunger games style alien book

Tags: story-identification

I was reading this book that was like a sci-fi hunger games thing. Basically this human from earth gets captured from his boat, and then he is taken to the alien's spaceship where he is thrown into jail.

All of the other prisoners are from other planets - they have a crocodile man, a small frail girl called Doe who can read minds. All of the aliens have some translation thing inserted into them so they can understand each other. So in the human's example, all of them translated into English.

There's a lot of things that go on, they train for the final fight(I think, I may be getting this confused with the Hunger Games), the human sleeps with another alien girl there, the small girl Doe reads his mind and he gets embarrassed that she knows that he slept with the alien girl, and eventually they get released into an arena or something where they are hunted by the hunter aliens who captured them.

A lot of stuff happens and Doe dies in the end. What is this book's name?

Comment: Hello Randor, welcome to [scifi.se] and thank you for your question. When did you read this book? Are there additional details you remember, for instance, what did it look like? You can [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/153819/edit) your question to add anything else you may remember. Meanwhile, have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: @SQB No I haven't taken the tour yet, I'll do that now, thanks for the advice :). I am actually very new to Stack Exchange; Puzzle SE, Stack Overflow, and Scifi are the only ones I'm currently browsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Humans abducted and sold as gladiators/slaves?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/humans-abducted-and-sold-as-gladiators-slaves)

Comment: @Otis I did the duplication the other way, since the answer to this one is much better.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have literally seen you everywhere on stack exchange - on Puzzle, on Literature, and even on Movies and TV....                                                                          God, is that you?

Comment: @G_as_in_Gnome Well, those and SFF are [my top sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/4859979/rand-althor?tab=accounts) ... I guess all it means is that you and I have similar taste in SE sites :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Allow me to correct myself then. Dad? is that you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to suggest *[Hunters of the Red Moon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/472220.Hunters_of_the_Red_Moon)* by Marion Zimmer Bradley and her brother, Paul Edwin Zimmer (often uncredited in the early releases of the book). To quote from one of the Goodreads reviews (emphasis mine):

> This is an adventure story into the vast unknown void of space. It's full of rich and interesting characters from a **huge 9 foot tall Protosaur (lizardman)** with a wonderful sense of humor to **a beautiful empath** and a sexy lady warrior. The Protagonist is interesting, dashing and handsome and the world they roam has an interesting history and a deadly secret.

....

> For a Synopsis listen to "Come Sail Away" by Styx. Except, these illegal aliens can't be confused with angels. They **abduct the main hero from a sailboat** in the middle of the ocean and the "renascence man" goes to the stars for the adventure of his life. The first part, escape from the Slavers that grabbed him! Can he team up with the 9 foot Lizard with the gentle, laid back disposition? Does he bite?

According to another review, the empath girl is named Dallith:

> Hunters is the story of Dane Marsh, who is abducted from Earth to an alien slave ship. He befriends a group of fellow captives who join together for an attempted escape. And one sees his new friends as a whole spectrum of unique characters. He meets Rianna, a streetsmart warrior girl, Aratak, a lizard like being who is wise and philosophical, (a bit of suprise to me as I would not expect these from a reptile crature), and the tender Dallith, an empath girl from Spica 4. Since she feels the emotions of other beings, we meet her as a weak character but she proves to be more tough than first glance.

It was followed by a sequel, *[The Survivors](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/472779.The_Survivors)*.

> The long unavailable SF classic from the authors of Hunters of the Red Moon. The Survivors--Dane, Rianna, and the monster Aratak--live to achieve fame and fortune after being hunted by fierce killers and shapeshifters, and accept the challenge of investigating a Closed World--where mysteries not yet explained by science exist . . . and danger abounds.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much :)